# DevSecOPs Q- how do you build in the capability to automate the ability to discover and apply security patches in your ci/cd pipeline?

Tags: continuous-integration, cicd, devsecops

Within a DevSecOps Ci/Cd pipeline one of the best practices is to automatically discover and apply patches to vulnerable software prior to deployment.

Is it possible to check a CVE database, find patches, and then deploy. I want to build this capability into my pipeline.

The environments applicable to the above is AWS and Azure.

Can you provide examples of tools I could use to achieve the above?

• Automatically discover and apply patches to vulnerable open-source software prior to deployment.

Answer (score 1):

A tool like Trivy may be your answer.

Trivy looks at the contents of an image to check which packages it includes, scans for all vulnerabilities, and sends them to AWS Security Hub.

If the scan does not uncover vulnerabilities, the Docker images are pushed to Amazon Elastic Container Registry for deployment.

To use Trivy, you must have Security Hub enabled in the AWS Region where you deploy this solution.

There are many other open-source solutions out there. Trivy is just one of them.